# Add a splash screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

i try to add a splash screen in flutter i place the splash image in drawable folder and update the launch_background.xml but the quality of image is very low as compare to original image.
How to get the original image in the splash

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Did you set different folders of drawable/xxxdpi for different sizes?

Comment: create different drawables for different screens, using a service like imagebake